# How to obtain suburb's polygon?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to obtain through geocoding service polygon not a single point on map?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your suburb in the form of a kml polygon. To do this you will need to know the points that form the boundary of this suburb.